# add elements with multiple values to existing xml file using powershell

Tags: xml, powershell

I am automating SQL Reporting services and i need to add proxy settings to the web.config file. I try to do this in powershell but i am unable to figure out how to do this through powershell.

I need to add the following piece of xml code to the end of an existing web.config XML file

```
  <system.net>
    <defaultProxy enabled="true" useDefaultCredentials="true">
      <proxy bypassonlocal="True" proxyaddress="http://ocs.kennisnet.nl:3128" />
    </defaultProxy>
  </system.net>
```

The complete xml file needs to be:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <pages validateRequest="false">
      <controls>
        <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
      </controls>
      <namespaces>
        <remove namespace="System.Linq" />
        <remove namespace="System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <identity impersonate="true" />
    <compilation defaultLanguage="c#" debug="false" targetFramework="4.0" tempDirectory="E:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services\SSRS\ReportServer\RSTempFiles">
      <assemblies>
        <clear />
        <add assembly="ReportingServicesWebServer" />
        <add assembly="System.Xml, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <add assembly="System.Xml.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.DynamicData, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <trace enabled="false" requestLimit="10" pageOutput="false" traceMode="SortByTime" localOnly="true" />
    <sessionState mode="Off" />
    <httpHandlers>
      <add verb="*" path="Reserved.ReportServer" type="Microsoft.ReportingServices.WebServer.ReportServiceHttpHandler, ReportingServicesWebServer" />
      <add verb="*" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, ReportingServicesWebServer, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" />
      <add verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" validate="false" />
    </httpHandlers>
    <httpModules>
      <clear />
      <add name="OutputCache" type="System.Web.Caching.OutputCacheModule" />
      <add name="WindowsAuthentication" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsAuthenticationModule" />
      <add name="FormsAuthentication" type="System.Web.Security.FormsAuthenticationModule" />
      <add name="PassportAuthentication" type="System.Web.Security.PassportAuthenticationModule" />
      <add name="RoleManager" type="System.Web.Security.RoleManagerModule" />
      <add name="UrlAuthorization" type="System.Web.Security.UrlAuthorizationModule" />
      <add name="FileAuthorization" type="System.Web.Security.FileAuthorizationModule" />
      <add name="AnonymousIdentification" type="System.Web.Security.AnonymousIdentificationModule" />
      <add name="Profile" type="System.Web.Profile.ProfileModule" />
      <add name="ErrorHandlerModule" type="System.Web.Mobile.ErrorHandlerModule, System.Web.Mobile, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
    </httpModules>
    <globalization requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8" />
    <httpRuntime executionTimeout="9000" requestValidationMode="2.0" />
    <securityPolicy>
      <trustLevel name="RosettaSrv" policyFile="rssrvpolicy.config" />
    </securityPolicy>
    <trust level="RosettaSrv" originUrl="" legacyCasModel="true" />
    <webServices>
      <soapExtensionTypes>
        <add type="Microsoft.ReportingServices.WebServer.RsSoapExtension, ReportingServicesWebServer" priority="1" group="1" />
      </soapExtensionTypes>
      <soapExtensionReflectorTypes>
        <add type="Microsoft.ReportingServices.WebServer.RsSoapExtensionReflector, ReportingServicesWebServer" />
      </soapExtensionReflectorTypes>
    </webServices>
  </system.web>
  <runtime>
    <alwaysFlowImpersonationPolicy enabled="true" />
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.ReportingServices.Interfaces" publicKeyToken="89845dcd8080cc91" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="8.0.242.0-14.0.0.0" newVersion="14.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.ReportingServices.ProcessingCore" publicKeyToken="89845dcd8080cc91" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="9.0.242.0-14.0.0.0" newVersion="14.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.ReportingServices.ProcessingObjectModel" publicKeyToken="89845dcd8080cc91" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="9.0.242.0-14.0.0.0" newVersion="14.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.SqlServer.Types" publicKeyToken="89845dcd8080cc91" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="10.0.0.0-14.0.0.0" newVersion="14.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="msmgdsrv" publicKeyToken="89845dcd8080cc91" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="9.0.0.0-14.0.0.0" newVersion="14.0.0.0" />
        <codeBase version="14.0.0.0" href="%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft Analysis Services\AS OLEDB\140\msmgdsrv.dll" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Cors" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.0.0.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <system.net>
    <defaultProxy enabled="true" useDefaultCredentials="true">
      <proxy bypassonlocal="True" proxyaddress="http://ocs.kennisnet.nl:3128" />
    </defaultProxy>
  </system.net>
</configuration>
```

I found a lot of code examples but none seem to work, i managed to create bellow code but it doesn't save the file, and i don't know how to add the second key values. Hopefully one of you are more skilled in this than i am ..

```bsh
$file="web.config"
[xml]$xmlDoc = [System.Xml.XmlDocument](Get-Content $file)

$newEl=$xmlDoc.CreateElement("system.net")
$xmlDoc.configuration.AppendChild($newEl)  
$xmlDoc.Save($file)

$newEl=$xmlDoc.CreateElement("defaultProxy")   
$nameAtt1=$xmlDoc.CreateAttribute("enabled")
$nameAtt1.psbase.value="true"  
$newEl.SetAttributeNode($nameAtt1)  

$nameAtt2=$xmlDoc.CreateAttribute("useDefaultCredentials")  
$nameAtt2.psbase.value="true"    
$newEl.SetAttributeNode($nameAtt2) 
$xmlDoc.configuration["system.net"].AppendChild($newEl)  

$xmlDoc.Save($file)
```

The eventual result need to create the complete XML file as shown above.

Please help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is also a way to use XElement.

```
using namespace "System.Xml.Linq"
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Xml.Linq

$configPath = Convert-Path "web.config"
$newElement = [XElement]@'
  <system.net>
    <defaultProxy enabled="true" useDefaultCredentials="true">
      <proxy bypassonlocal="True" proxyaddress="http://ocs.kennisnet.nl:3128" />
    </defaultProxy>
  </system.net>
'@

$configuration = [XElement]::Load($configPath)
$configuration.Add($newElement)
$configuration.ToString() | Out-File "new.config"
```

Comment: This seems to be the most easy to use, to just add the code block i need to add to the xml file, however i receive at the load section the following error message:


Unable to find type [XElement].
At C:\OneDrive\Kennisnet\Vensters - SODK - DPO - Vensters TMG\scripts\install_sql_reporting\acc\xml_test.ps1:12 char:18
+ $configuration = [XElement]::Load($configPath)
+                  ~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (XElement:TypeName) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFound

Comment: Ps. I run this on windows server 2016 with powershell version 4.0.

Answer (score 2):

The following will insert the new XML data after the runtime element:

```
$webconfig = [xml](Get-Content C:\temp\web.config)
$newxml = [xml](Get-Content c:\temp\new.xml)

$newNode = $webconfig.ImportNode($newxml.'system.net',$true)
$InsertAfterNode = $webconfig.configuration.runtime
$null = $webconfig.configuration.insertAfter($newNode,$InsertAfterNode)
$webconfig.Save("c:\temp\web.config")
```

`$newNode` exists so that we have the correct object type for the `InsertAfter()` method. The corresponding `ImportNode()` method outputs the object type we want. `$true` is passed so that we import all descendant elements of `system.net`.

I used full paths when working with the files. I believe the `.Save()` method typically requires a full path because it defaults to a specific directory. Please note that this is not generic code and relies on you specifically providing the element from where you want to insert new data.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing the following:

```bsh
$newXml = @'
  <system.net>
    <defaultProxy enabled="true" useDefaultCredentials="true">
      <proxy bypassonlocal="True" proxyaddress="http://ocs.kennisnet.nl:3128" />
    </defaultProxy>
  </system.net>
</configuration>
'@

$File = ".\web.config" 

# Remove last line of file
$Content = Get-Content $File
$Output = $Content[0..($Content.count - 2)]

Out-File -FilePath $File -InputObject $Output

# Add code block to file
Add-Content -Path ".\web.config" -Value $newXml
```

This is not the nicest thing to use as i assume the last line of the file is always the same but it sure works for me.

To bad i couldn't get the code to work as suggested by rokumaru as this would be the best to use and i hope he will complement this code to get it working.